# HttpClient and RestTemplate - Concurrency exception

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, httpclient, resttemplate

I'm using the following configuration :

```
<bean id="httpClient" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
    <!-- <constructor-arg ref="httpClientParams"/> -->
 </bean>

 <bean id="httpClientFactory"
    class="org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpClient" />
</bean>

 <bean id="restTemplate" name="restTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate"
    autowire-candidate="true">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpClientFactory" />
```

My environment is using multiple threads that tries to invoke restTemplate.

I get the following warning from time to time:

```
 WARN SimpleHttpConnectionManager - SimpleHttpConnectionManager being used incorrectly.  Be sure that HttpMethod.releaseConnection() is always called and that only one thread and/or method is using this connection manager at a time.
```

followed by the exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.isStale(HttpConnection.java:515)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.closeIfStale(HttpConnection.java:431)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:382)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
at org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(CommonsClientHttpRequest.java:85)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:46)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:49)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:488)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:452)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:302)
```

Any ideas how to fix my configuration?

P.S I tried the following with no success:

```
<bean id="httpClient" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpClientParams" />
</bean>

<bean id="httpClientParams" class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpClientParams">
    <property name="connectionManagerClass"
        value="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager" />
</bean>
```

Comment: You seem to be using an extremely old version of Apache Http client. Is there a reason you can't upgrade?

Comment: Try using the default constructor for CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory, which ought to configure a multithreaded connection manager already. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/http/client/CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory.html